# What does 'only supported in ash' mean?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I was reading the documentation recently and got stuck on this part.

From http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html#type-CreateWindowOptions

> transparentBackground ( optional boolean )
>
> Enable window background transparency. **Only supported in ash.** Requires experimental API permission.

Soo... What is Ash? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the feature is available only in ChromeOS.

Comment: Aha, thank you. Do you have any idea where the "ash = chromeOS" comes from? Makes no sense to me. Codename?

Answer (score 5):

"Ash (the Aura SHell) is the ChromeOS window manager"

"Aura is the hardware accelerated UI framework built on CC."

- From a chromium-dev email [Explainer: Aura and Ash #defines & dependencies](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/chromium-dev/hjCJUQyJrvs/emK1Di7pS-cJ)

Also, see a [block diagram of Aura and dependencies](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura/aura-and-shell-dependencies).